# JQuery - Quick Sand JQuery (Default Selection)

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm using http://razorjack.net/quicksand/ this jquery.
I want to select 'application' instead of 'everything' in page load.
Is there anyway to do?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".class").trigger('click');
   });
</script>
```

answered May 12 '11 at 15:56 
Elaine Marley
[using quicksand plugin to get specific data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328140/using-quicksand-plugin-to-get-specific-data)